# React: How to make this design for hierarchy component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is the image
[image]

I am expecting the same design as above the image.
There will one root parent node and parent could have multiple child and their child could have multiple child.

Tried the tree view from @mui/lab but didn't get exact UI
Here is my styled tree item

```
const StyledTreeItem2 = styled(TreeItem)(({ rootNode }) => {
  const borderColor = "gray";
  return {
    position: "relative",
    "&:before": {
      pointerEvents: "none",
      content: '""',
      position: "absolute",
      width: 32,
      left: -16,
      top: 66,
      borderBottom:
        // only display if the TreeItem is not root node
        !rootNode ? `1px dashed ${borderColor}` : "none"
    },
    "&.MuiTreeItem-root > .MuiTreeItem-content:hover": {
      background: "transparent"
    },
    "&.MuiTreeItem-root > .MuiTreeItem-content.Mui-selected": {
      background: "transparent"
    },
    "&.MuiTreeItem-root > .MuiTreeItem-content.Mui-selected:hover": {
      background: "transparent"
    },
    [`& .${treeItemClasses.group}`]: {
      marginLeft: 16,
      paddingLeft: 18,
      borderLeft: `1px dashed ${borderColor}`
    }
  };
});
```

got this
[image]

Here some extra line is coming.